# DATE_ADD functionality in Ingres

Tags: sql, ingres, date-math

Many (most? nearly all?) SQL dialects have a way to perform this type of function:
date_add( MyDate, MyInterval )

I've been through all of the docs, but I cannot find this functionality in Ingres. My immediate goal is to get "MyDate plus 3 months". Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Note: I realize that it's **possible** to achieve this with existing SQL. But it will involve:

- extract the month from my date
- add 3 to this number
- extract the day and year from my date
- use the new day, month, year to create a new date
- But I also need to test to see if I cross a year boundary, so there will be a CASE statement as well

That's an awful lot of SQL for something that's so simple in Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and all the others I can think of. It makes me hopeful that I'm somehow missing a much simpler alternative.

Comment: Ckech this link: http://ariel.its.unimelb.edu.au/~yuan/Ingres/us_13229.html They show some tricks using Ingres and date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a link to hand.  Search your documentation for 'date arithmetic' and/or the 'interval' datatype.

Here's an example, which is not dissimilar to your english statement of what you want:

```
DATE('23-oct-09') + '3 months'
```

Comment: Hooray! I knew there should be a simple solution... and that's mighty simple. The precise string to search for is "Date/Time Arithmetic" for anyone else that needs it. I guess I was hung up on thinking there must be a function.